What are the final upgrades for Jack's gear/body in Lone Echo II?
In the Lone Echo II VR game, you can scan things to add upgrade progress to different parts of Jack's gear/body (for clarity, Jack is robot you play as).
You can upgrade your reactive cutter, your radioactivity shield, your maneuvering jets, and maybe some other stuff that I haven't discovered yet.
What's the final upgrade for each part of Jack's body/gear?
